# Mikrotik port forwarding - no access to server

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv4, mikrotik, owncloud

I need your help concerning port forwarding with Mikrotik's RouterOS!

I have executed this command :

```
/ip firewall nat add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat  comment="Owncloud in NAT" dst-port=8079 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=172.16.0.50 to-ports=8079
```

My server is plugged in my ether3

It opened the port in question, but the request is not going to the server so when I try to open the web page hosted on that port I receive a 404 error.

If you are missing information, don't be shy to ask me to add more details!
I am not used to debug Mikrotik product, since this is my first one!

** UPDATE **

I am not able to access my server from the WAN interface, I am able to access my server inside my network.

** SOLUTION **

I solved my problem, I have noticed that if I use the LTE on my phone to access my server, it works. So I added a static DNS to access my server inside my network

I did :

```
ip dns> set servers=.8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 \
\... allow-remote-requests=yes
```

to set google dns servers and then I added my static dns :

```
ip dns static> add name=www.exemple.com address=172.16.0.50
```

Comment: Its been a while since I've had to mess around with Mikrotik's but that looks correct.  Also, a 404 error IS a response from your server.  If your browser could not communicate at all to the server over that port it wouldn't then respond to you with an error.  Is this a linux based machine?  I would attempt to connect again and then review and/or post the details of your access.log and error.log.  Alternatively you could just tail -f /your/log/file.log and watch what happens live as you attempt to connect.

Comment: Well, I have 404 when I am trying to reach my server using the WAN address. If I communicate with the server in my network, it works.

Comment: And what does your access log on the server say when its serving out the 404 page?  A 404 error is still a response, its not a timeout or a refusal.  Something in your network is responding.
You can also run Torch on your servers internal IP address and see if you see the connection pop up from your WAN.  

https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Troubleshooting_tools

Actually, if memory services there is a TCP connection list in the firewall.

Comment: /ip firewall connection

Comment: I will have a look into that! Thank you! I will come back with my results.

Comment: It must be the Mikrotik that answer that but I see nothing. I will investigate more

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out @SamK, I found the problem I had and wrote the edits explaining what I did to fix my issue!

Comment: Please don't use words like 'SOLVED" in question titles. This doesn't mark a question as solved. If the question truly is solved, please post an answer and then mark the answer.

Comment: @JeffLabonté Please put the solution as an answer.